# Limit the movement of the cube

Tags: javascript, html, css, cube

How to limit the movement of this cube to just up and down, left and right?
I want to remove the diagonal movement. When someone touches or move it diagonally I want it to move neither left or right defends where do they touch.

you can check the working file: http://jsfiddle.net/7Lg87gzu/4/

Here is the js code

```
$(function(){

    var el = document.createElement('div'),
        transformProps = 'transform WebkitTransform MozTransform OTransform msTransform'.split(' '),
        transformProp = support(transformProps),
        transitionDuration = 'transitionDuration WebkitTransitionDuration MozTransitionDuration OTransitionDuration msTransitionDuration'.split(' '),
        transitionDurationProp = support(transitionDuration);

    function support(props) {
        for(var i = 0, l = props.length; i < l; i++) {
            if(typeof el.style[props[i]] !== "undefined") {
                return props[i];
            }
        }
    }

    var mouse = {
            start : {}
        },
        touch = document.ontouchmove !== undefined,
        viewport = {
            x: -10,
            y: 20,
            el: $('.cube')[0],
            move: function(coords) {
                if(coords) {
                    if(typeof coords.x === "number") this.x = coords.x;
                    if(typeof coords.y === "number") this.y = coords.y;
                }

                this.el.style[transformProp] = "rotateX("+this.x+"deg) rotateY("+this.y+"deg)";
            },
            reset: function() {
                this.move({x: 0, y: 0});
            }
        };

    viewport.duration = function() {
        var d = touch ? 50 : 2000;
        viewport.el.style[transitionDurationProp] = d + "ms";
        return d;
    }();

    $(document).keydown(function(evt) {
        switch(evt.keyCode)
        {
            case 37: // left
                viewport.move({y: viewport.y - 90});
                break;

            case 38: // up
                evt.preventDefault();
                viewport.move({x: viewport.x + 90});
                break;

            case 39: // right
                viewport.move({y: viewport.y + 90});
                break;

            case 40: // down
                evt.preventDefault();
                viewport.move({x: viewport.x - 90});
                break;

            case 27: //esc
                viewport.reset();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        };
    }).bind('mousedown touchstart', function(evt) {
        delete mouse.last;
        if($(evt.target).is('a, iframe')) {
            return true;
        }

        evt.originalEvent.touches ? evt = evt.originalEvent.touches[0] : null;
        mouse.start.x = evt.pageX;
        mouse.start.y = evt.pageY;
        $(document).bind('mousemove touchmove', function(event) {
            // Only perform rotation if one touch or mouse (e.g. still scale with pinch and zoom)
            if(!touch || !(event.originalEvent && event.originalEvent.touches.length > 1)) {
                event.preventDefault();
                // Get touch co-ords
                event.originalEvent.touches ? event = event.originalEvent.touches[0] : null;
                $('.viewport').trigger('move-viewport', {x: event.pageX, y: event.pageY});
            }
        });

        $(document).bind('mouseup touchend', function () {
            $(document).unbind('mousemove touchmove');
        });
    });

    $('.viewport').bind('move-viewport', function(evt, movedMouse) {

        // Reduce movement on touch screens
        var movementScaleFactor = touch ? 4 : 1;

        if (!mouse.last) {
            mouse.last = mouse.start;
        } else {
            if (forward(mouse.start.x, mouse.last.x) != forward(mouse.last.x, movedMouse.x)) {
                mouse.start.x = mouse.last.x;
            }
            if (forward(mouse.start.y, mouse.last.y) != forward(mouse.last.y, movedMouse.y)) {
                mouse.start.y = mouse.last.y;
            }
        }

        viewport.move({
            x: viewport.x + parseInt((mouse.start.y - movedMouse.y)/movementScaleFactor),
            y: viewport.y - parseInt((mouse.start.x - movedMouse.x)/movementScaleFactor)
        });

        mouse.last.x = movedMouse.x;
        mouse.last.y = movedMouse.y;

        function forward(v1, v2) {
            return v1 >= v2 ? true : false;
        }
    });

    /* Just for fun */
  /*  if(!touch) {
        $('.cube > div').eq(2).html('<object width="360" height="360"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/MY5PkidV1cM?fs=1&amp;hl=en_GB&amp;rel=0"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="#" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="360" height="360"></embed></object>');
    }*/

});
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen when someone touches or moves the mouse in a diagonal direction?  The keys already only go up/down and left/right.

Comment: when the someone touches the mouse diagonal I just want to move it neither right or left.

Comment: Only allow movement if only 1 directional key is depressed.

Comment: what do you mean @Carcigenicate?

Comment: @winresh24 Instead of moving directly on a key press, add it to a list of pressed keys, and if the list has more than one directional key in it, either don't translate any of the key presses into movement, or only move in the direction of the first pressed key.

Comment: can you show me how to do it? @Carcigenicate

Comment: @winresh24 Sorry, I don't know javascript. Inside your switch statement that you're currently using to handle keypresses, instead of calling the move function on each key press, add each keypress to a list as it's pressed, make sure there is only 1 directional key pressed, then move in that direction.